# Creating custom display template with search result web part

Tags: display-template

I am required to create a display template programatically which is via visual studio and I am really new to this. Can anyone share with me a sample source code for creating display templates and how to use them in Sharepoint? Thanks in advance, appreciate it :)

Answer (score 1):

The following article from official sources should give you a start.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/sharepoint-design-manager-display-templates

There can be a fair bit involved depending on what you are trying to achieve. More often than not I find most customisation can start from an a copy of an existing template. This can be achieved by opening the Master Page Gallery-> Display Templates and copying an existing template. A template will generally consist of a *.html and *.js of which are both associated.

If you do wish to start from a blank display template I can recommend the following starter template from Elio Struyf.

https://www.eliostruyf.com/starter-javascript-display-templates-for-your-projects/